# UrbanAirship push notification with custom icon

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have recently started using Urban Airship for my company. I have to create a custom layout for the push notification. My problem is I need to get the url of image in order to set the icon inside the remote view using Picasso. Everyone is setting the notification icon using drawables which are present inside the resource folder. Moreover, I did not find any getter method that can give me the image url.

Also, I was not able to find any good example that is solving the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to send the URL as an extra. Example using the [push API:](https://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua/#push-api)

```
"notification": {
   "alert": "Notification alert",

   "android": {
     "extra": {
        "url": "some url"
      }
   }
}
```

If you are using the composer, you can set extras under the android overrides.

Then on the device you can access the extra using:

```
String url = message.getExtra("url", null);
```

Or if you are using an older SDK version:

```
String url = message.getPushBundle().getString("url");
```

Comment: I am using remote views  to make my notification customizable. Inside the view I have one ImageView. I just want to put the icon inside that image view. So everything is woking fine if I hardcoded the image url. In that case case I am using picasso to fetch the icon through that url and put that thing inside the same imageView. But my problem is I am not  able to get the image url itself from the urban airship Pushmessage payload as they don't have any getter method to retrieve the url.

Comment: You can send the URL as an extra to the SDK and fetch it using `message.getExtra("icon_url", null)` on SDK 8.5+

Answer (score 0):

Paste this method in your class:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}
```

Call this method to get the bitmap from url:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_USER_ID/picture?type=large"); // Change the url with your own url.
```

And in your notification object set this image like this:

```
builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
```

For Urban Airship there is also a way to send and receive multiple values, you can send values (String, Sound Name, Json etc) through Payload. I'll suggest you to send your url as a key value pair in Json and get it in your App through Json. Check this link:

https://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/python/1.0.0/push.html#notification-payload

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zohaib. I don't have any problem in retrieving the icon from the server. I am using Picasso for that. But my problem is getting the url of the itself. I get the Push message payload from the urbanairship server , but the payload does not have any getter  to retrieve the icon url. Please let me know if I am not making this clear